# Is there a way to intercept the sound coming out of my speakers so that I can insert a C#.NET software-based audio filter?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, audio-streaming

I suffer from tinnitus, and there are a number of sound-based therapies that I can use to mitigate the phantom sounds.

I would like to explore the possibility of processing the sound going to my headphones, or even my speakers, from my PC with a software-based filter.

Is there a way using C# to intercept the audio stream, process it (applying a band-pass filter for example), allowing it to continue to external devices?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve what you are describing would be to write a custom audio driver for the device in question (speakers or headphones. If that is the case then unfortunately no it would not be possible in C#. Drivers are written in a mix of C++ and assembler.

Comment: Many thanks.  I guess I should look at writing an audio player tool and building the filters into that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use virtual audio device to capture the sound and transmit it to the real speakers after processing. I'm not sure if it is possible to create this using c#. But you can use existing drivers like [vac](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm). So you set vac as default device. You create a c# program which records from vac, does the processing, and sends it to the speakers.